# How to convert this timestamp format to another format in Perl?

Tags: debian, perl, posix, weka, machine-learning

I am trying to design a Perl/... approach which converts my timestamp format (`ddMMyyyy-HHmm+0300`) into the timestamp/time/... format (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:00`) used by WEKA data analysis system. 
I am initially making the WEKA data file from `paste` command and the removal of the first column with `AWK`. 
There should not be any limitations which would make the problem harder than it is actually, but possibly the quotes in the first variable. 
I think the approach (3) can be most feasible i.e. use directly `POSIX::strftime` function (Deathgrip)

1. Hard problem in Section 1
2. Easier approach without quotes in the data in Section 2
3. `POSIX::strftime` approach and similar thread [Perl strptime format differs from strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003993/perl-strptime-format-differs-from-strftime)

Example of the input

```
23072017-2200+0300
```

- Expected output

  ```
  2017-07-23'T'22:00:00
  ```

Full example of CSV line without quotes but with underscores so can be harder

```
 Ni, Aika, Aika_l, Un, Unen, Unen_kesto, Uniluokat_R, Uniluokat_k, Uniluokat_s, HRV_RMSSD_a, HRV_RMSSD_i, Kokonaisp, Palautumisen_k, Hermoston_t, Syke_ave_m, Syke_a, Syke_l, Hengitystiheys_ave_m, Hengitystiheys_a, Hengitystiheys_min_a, Liikeaktiivisuus_l, Liikeaktiivisuus_a, Paivamaara_l
 "Masi", 23072010-2200+0300, 24072010-0600+0300, 70, 7h40, 6h30, 1h40, 3h40, 1h10, 67.0, 43.0, 24.0, 430, 30, 70, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 150, 260, 24.10.2010
 "Masi", 23072010-2200+0300, 24072010-0600+0300, 70, 7h40, 6h30, 1h40, 3h40, 1h10, 67.0, 43.0, 24.0, 430, 30, 70, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 150, 260, 24.10.2010
```

Expected output

```
 Ni, Aika, Aika_l, Un, Unen, Unen_kesto, Uniluokat_R, Uniluokat_k, Uniluokat_s, HRV_RMSSD_a, HRV_RMSSD_i, Kokonaisp, Palautumisen_k, Hermoston_t, Syke_ave_m, Syke_a, Syke_l, Hengitystiheys_ave_m, Hengitystiheys_a, Hengitystiheys_min_a, Liikeaktiivisuus_l, Liikeaktiivisuus_a, Paivamaara_l
 "Masi", 2010-07-23'T‌​'22:00:00, 2010-07-24'T‌​'06:00:00, 70, 7h40, 6h30, 1h40, 3h40, 1h10, 67.0, 43.0, 24.0, 430, 30, 70, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 150, 260, 24.10.2010
 "Masi", 2010-07-23'T‌​'22:00:00, 2010-07-24'T‌​'06:00:00, 70, 7h40, 6h30, 1h40, 3h40, 1h10, 67.0, 43.0, 24.0, 430, 30, 70, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 150, 260, 24.10.2010
```

### 1. Attempt script which you can call by `script.pl filename`

I think the use of parser `Text::CSV` is too complicated because my data set is simpler than the use case. 
So I think a simple regex approach can be possible

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995620/54964

## Data prepared like this for the script
# paste -d" " log.csv data.csv | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' > weka.data.csv
# cp $HOME/Data/weka.data.csv $HOME/Workspace/
#
# Maybe, this all could be integrated into Perl script

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } );

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( \*ARGV ) ) {
    s/\n/ /g for @$row;
    $csv->print( \*STDOUT, $row );

    # TODO regex
    #convert ddMMyyyy-HHmm+0300 to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:00    
}
```

### 2. Perl Regex approach

Pseudocode where the approach cannot work because there are no variable replacements like carrying `dd` to the result

```
# TODO s/ddMMyyyy-HHmm+0300/$3-$2-$1'T'$4:$5:00/;
perl -pe s/([0-3][0-9])(([0-1][0-9]))(20[0-9]{2})([0-2][0-9])([0-5][0-9])+0300/$3-$2-$1'T'$4:$5:00/;
```

where

- `dd` by `([0-3][0-9])` / `$3`
- similarly for `MM` by `([0-1][0-9])` / `$2`
- `yyyy` similarly like `(20[0-9]{2})` / `$1`
- `-` literally
- `HH` 24H time by `([0-5][0-9])` / `$4`
- `mm` by `([0-5][0-9])`) / `$5`
- `+0300` / remove simply

It would be great to have the regex in some more readable format.

### Testing Sundeep's proposal in comment

Code

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995620/54964

s='"Masi", 23072010-2200+0300, 24072010-0600+0300 70, 7h40'

echo "$s" | perl -pe 's/\b(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d{4})-(\d\d)(\d\d)\+\d{4}\b/$3-$2-$1\x27T<200c><200b>\x27$4:$5:00/g' y $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } );
```

Output is as expected for one line

```
"Masi", 2010-07-23'T‌​'22:00:00, 2010-07-24'T‌​'06:00:00, 70, 7h40
```

Applying on the complete line by just replacing the variable `s` content, output as expected

```
"Masi", 2010-07-23'T‌​'22:00:00, 2010-07-24'T‌​'06:00:00, 70, 7h40, 6h30, 1h40, 3h40, 1h10, 67.0, 43.0, 24.0, 430, 30, 70, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 150, 260, 24.10.2010
```

TODO complete approach with multiline approach with capability to skip the header

### Testing Deathgrip's motivated proposal

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995620/54964

use strict;
use warnings;
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007784/54964
# http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html
use Time::Piece;
use POSIX;

# TODO breaks because of false brackets
#my $input = '"Masi", 2010-07-23'T<200c><200b>'22:00:00, 2010-07-24'T<200c><200b>'06:00:00, 70, 7h40, 6h30, 1h40, 3h40, 1h10, 67.0, 43.0, 24.0, 430, 30, 70, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 150, 260, 24.10.2010'

my $str = '23072017-2200+0300';
my $f = '%d%m%dY-%H%M+0300';
#my $t = POSIX::strftime($str, $f); # fails!
my $t = strftime($str, $f); # fails!

print "$t\n";
```

Output

```
Usage: POSIX::strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1) at prepare.data3.pl line 22.
```

OS: Debian 9

Comment: assuming sample string, `s='"Masi", 23072010-2200+0300, 24072010-0600+0300 70, 7h40'` ... is this what you are looking for? `echo "$s" | perl -pe 's/\b(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d{4})-(\d\d)(\d\d)\+\d{4}\b/$3-$2-$1\x27T\x27$4:$5:00/g'` ... suggest to show 2-3 lines each from log.csv data.csv and post complete expected output for that...

Comment: Have you considered using `Time::Local` (http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) and the `strftime` function in the `POSIX` module (http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) to do the conversion?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - See the links in my comment.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I'd rather prefer to understand complete question and answer it... the one in comment is only date fmt conversion... hence why I suggest you to add few lines from both input files and add expected output for that

Comment: I wrote `strftime` not str**p**time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ perl -pe 's/\b(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d{4})-(\d\d)(\d\d)\+\d{4}\b/$3-$2-$1\x27T\x27$4:$5:00/g' ip.csv
 Ni, Aika, Aika_l Un, Unen, Unen_kesto, Uniluokat_R, Uniluokat_k, Uniluokat_s, HRV_RMSSD_a, HRV_RMSSD_i, Kokonaisp, Palautumisen_k, Hermoston_t, Syke_ave_m, Syke_a, Syke_l, Hengitystiheys_ave_m, Hengitystiheys_a, Hengitystiheys_min_a, Liikeaktiivisuus_l, Liikeaktiivisuus_a, Paivamaara_l
 "Masi", 2010-07-23'T'22:00:00, 2010-07-24'T'06:00:00 70, 7h40, 6h30, 1h40, 3h40, 1h10, 67.0, 43.0, 24.0, 430, 30, 70, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 150, 260, 24.10.2010
 "Masi", 2010-07-23'T'22:00:00, 2010-07-24'T'06:00:00 70, 7h40, 6h30, 1h40, 3h40, 1h10, 67.0, 43.0, 24.0, 430, 30, 70, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10, 150, 260, 24.10.2010
```

- `\b` is word boundary
- `(\d\d)` captures two consecutive digits, `(\d{4})` captures four of them and so on
- `\x27` is for single quotes. If there can be unrelated digits after this, perhaps better to use octal representation `\047`
- as the search and replacement is only for specific `ddMMyyyy-HHmm+0300` format, it won't affect the header. Still if needed, just add `if $.>1` after the substitute command

Probably the `paste+awk` commands used to create the input can be incorporated easily to this command, but would need that info added to question

Comment: I corrected the typo `Aika_l Un` to `Aika_l, Un`. I hope it does not affect your proposal. What do you think? Maybe, one more field in your approach.

Comment: nope it won't affect... just another data which won't match the regex

Comment: Actually, not because the change is only in the header so your code works still, although I fixed the typo in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would have done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995620/54964

use strict;
use warnings;
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007784/54964
# http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw(strptime);

my $str = '23072017-2200+0300';
my $dtime = strptime( '%d%m%Y-%H%M%z', $str );
my $f = '%Y-%m-%d\'T\'%H:%M:%S';
my $t = strftime( $f, 0, $dtime->minute, $dtime->hour, $dtime->day, $dtime->month-1, $dtime->year-1900, -1, -1, $dtime->time_zone );

print "$t\n";
```

Output as expected on the time field

```
2017-07-23'T'22:00:00
```